# Disparate result after setting requires_grad=True

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am currently using PyTorch for deep neural network. I wrote a toy neural network shown below and I found that whether or not I set `requires_grad=True` for label `y` makes huge difference. When `y.requires_grad=True`, the neural network diverges. I am wondering why this happens.

```
import torch

x = torch.unsqueeze(torch.linspace(-1, 1, 100), dim=1)
y = x.pow(2) + 10 * torch.rand(x.size())


x.requires_grad = True
# this is where problem occurs
y.requires_grad = True

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden)
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.hidden(x))
        x = self.predict(x)
        return x

net = Net(1, 10, 1)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.5)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()


for t in range(200):
    y_pred = net(x)

    loss= criterion(y_pred, y)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    print("Epoch {}: {}".format(t, loss))
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: why do you `require_grad` for your inputs? are you trying to "learn" them?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using an outdated version of PyTorch. In more recent versions (0.4.0+), this will throw you the following error:

```
AssertionError: nn criterions don't compute the gradient w.r.t. targets - 
                please mark these tensors as not requiring gradients
```

Essentially, it tells you that it will only work if you set the `requires_grad` flag to `False` for your targets. The reason why this works at all in prior versions is indeed very interesting, and also why it causes diverging behavior.

My guess would be that a backwards pass would then also change your *targets* (instead of only changing your weights), which is obviously something you do not desire.